# ReactJs Routing - Not able to redirect to new page

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am redirecting my page to new page based on Button Click. It is actually hitting to new page url in browser, but not loading new component. I am using following code

```
Managepage.tsx
  <Link to="/newPublication">
                      <button className='metadata-btn' >Add New Publication</button>
                </Link>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/newPublication"   >
                     {NewPublication}
                    </Route>
                    {/* <Route path="/"   >
                    {NewPublication}
                    </Route> */}
              </Routes>

NewPublication.tsx file.

const NewPublication = () => {


return (
       
<div> test</div>
  
);

 }
export default NewPublication;
```

Comment: I am redirecting my page to new page based on Button Click. It is actually hitting to new page url in browser, but not loading new component. I am using Router in my App.js and as well in other Component. It looks like Router inside other Router not working (throwing error in console). I am using react-router-dom version @6.0.2 what is alternative approach to redirect pages ? other than downgrading to version 5.x ?

Comment: I resolved this Issue by using Router, Routes, Route implemented in App.tsx and Nested routing achieved using <Outlet/> to kick off its children.